# Splitting a dataframe based in a column

Tags: r, loops, split, chr

I would like to split my `data.frame` depending of a column tagged as `"Chr"`. I would like to write these splitted objects in a `.txt` file automatically too.

My input:

```
Name   Chr  Position LTR
Prob1   1     55     0.2
Prob2   2     25     0.9
Prob3   3     25     0.7
Prob4   1     45     0.5
```

My First output:

```
Name   Chr  Position  LTR 
Prob1   1      55     0.2
Prob4   1      45     0.5
```

My second output:

```
 Name   Chr  Position  LTR 
 Prob2   2     25      0.9
```

My last output:

```
Name   Chr  Position  LTR 
Prob3   3     25      0.7
```

I am trying to do something like:

`outfile <- paste0("newsplit",i,".txt")
SPLIT PROCEDURES
write.table(all, outfile, sep=";")`

Where `"i"` is the correspondent chromosome (value in a `"Chr"` collumn).

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First split your data.frame.

```
df.split <-split(df,df$Chr)# where df is your original dataframe 
           #and we split on Chr
```

Now, write it out to separate tab-separated files

```
lapply(names(df.split),function(x)
            write.table(file = paste0("df",x,".txt"),
            df.split[[x]], sep = "\t"))
```